# No indention for wrapfigure captions

Tags: floats, captions, koma-script, wrapfigure

I want to remove the indention of wrapfigure captions but NOT for normal figure captions. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[tbp]
      \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}A figure!\end{minipage}}
      \caption{\blindtext}
    \end{figure}%
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{5cm}
      \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}A figure!\end{minipage}}
      \caption{For this caption I don't want an indention!}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `caption` package and a local `\captionsetup{format=plain}` command:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{5cm}
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}A figure!\end{minipage}}
  \captionsetup{format=plain}
  \caption{For this caption I don't want an indention!}
 \end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{.9\textwidth}A figure!\end{minipage}}
  \caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With standard methods it would be possible to make this automatic:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\wrapfloat}{\captionsetup{format=plain}}
```

should suffice.

[image]

Comment: You can also say `\captionsetup[wrapfigure]{format=plain}` in the preamble (no need for `etoolbox` nor `\pretocmd`). Of course, one will require something like this for each type of wrap float, but usually there shouldn't be many of these.